# Defun with optional args inside the lambda?

Tags: emacs, lambda

I want to call defun with optional args inside the lambda:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-S-v") 
                (lambda ()
                  (interactive) (bk-cleans-text nil 2)))
```

The function works as standalone:

```
(bk-cleans-text nil 2)
```

But when called inside the lambda it complains on `cond`:

```
(defun bk-cleans-text (&optional killIt ParsSepBy)
  (interactive)

      (cond 
       ((= 1 ParsSepBy)
        (setq Find "\n+")
        (setq Replace "\n"))
       ((= 2 ParsSepBy)
        (setq Find "\n\n+")
        (setq Replace "\n\n"))
       (t
        (setq Find "\n+")
        (setq Replace "")))

      (message "F: %s, R: %s" Find Replace))
```

Comment: What error message do you get?  Could you try `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and paste the stacktrace (it shouldn't be very long) into the question?

Comment: @legoscia: Nicolas were right - the problem was in the key I've tried to map to. I changed the key - and it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the key combination that you have chosen. I used another one and it worked.